# How to make pytest to pass test if any parametrized test passed?

Tags: testing, pytest, fixtures, testinfra

We have a cluster where only a single server (master) can return a meaningful result. The master is selected automatically and at test time I don't know who is master and who is not. In our tests we are using testinfra which gives us a fixture 'host' for each host in cluster.

We have a test which looks like this:

```
def test_cluster(host):
    assert host.run_command('cluster --is_ok').stdout == 'OK'
```

The problem is that there are N hosts, and only one of them can return OK, others says "I'm not a master".

The normal output looks like this:

```
test_cluster[host1] .... FAIL
test_cluster[host2] .... OK
test_cluster[host3] .... FAIL
test_cluster[host4] .... FAIL
```

I want to find a way to mark the test `test_cluster` as pass if any of tests is pass (and fail if all tests are failed).

If testinfra is too much for the test, here the more concise example with pytest only:

```
@pytest.fixture.parametrize("num", [0, 0, 1, 0])
def test_example(num):
     asssert num > 0
```

I need pytest to pass if there is at least one `1` in 'num' fixture.

Comment: If some test is expected to fail, mark it with `@pytest.mark.xfail`.

Comment: `@pytest.mark.xfail` marks all instances of the test, and I need to fail if all instances failed.

Comment: I see. What do you expect the custom behaviour to be, exit with zero if any of `test_cluster` tests passes?

Comment: If all instances of the test failed -> test failed. If at least one from parametrization passes, then the test pass. (It's not about generic 'all tests' it's about tests after parametrization within parametrization group).

Comment: That's not how parametrize should be used, those aren't separate test cases with the same expected outcome; the correct test for your second example would be something like `assert any(num > 0 for num in [0, 0, 1, 0])`.

Comment: In my case the fixture for parametrization is `host` (from testinfra) and it represents different servers (provided by Ansible inventory). I can do my test with custom code to connect to all servers in sequence, but it's very much an anti-pattern for testinfra, so I would prefer to have a way to have fixture-wide assert (or cross-test assert? How should I call it?).